# Does Hazelcast create topics lazily?

Tags: hazelcast

Does Hazelcast lazily create topics. In the example below, we're calling getTopic('default'). If default topic doesn't exist, does Hazelcast automatically create it?

Does this mean there's no reason to initialize all the possible topics in the universe?

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        Topic topic = Hazelcast.getTopic ("default");  
        topic.addMessageListener(sample);       
        topic.publish ("my-message-object");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Hazelcast will create every distributed data structure lazily. You don't have to define anything. It will always automatically create it.